# Можно ли сделать POST-запрос при нажатии на произвольный элемент (не button)?

Tags: html

Хочется сделать красивые кнопки через CSS, т.е. не используя кнопки и картинки. GET запрос прописывается в виде ссылки, и все работает хорошо. Но не красиво в строке URL/
Можно ли как-то отправить POST запрос при нажатии, допустим, на div?

Comment: И без javascript'ов. С ними сделать легко, но, вдруг у пользователя они отключены? 0_о

Comment: А вдруг у пользователя нет браузера? что вы будете делать тогда? Надо предусмотреть!!!!

Comment: Если нет браузера то и сайт ему не нужен, а новости он получает на e-mail, телефон или по радио. На крайний случай есть даже План Б - бабульки у подъезда)

Comment: к тому же, не на всех мобильных браузерах нормально поддерживаются скрипты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно иметь скрытую форму и через JS вызвать метод submit() у неё.

```
<form id = "myform" action="./index" method = "post" style = "display:none;">
</form>
<div onclick = 'document.getElementById("myform").submit();'>Отправка формы</div>
```

Comment: Через JS я знаю как делать, хотелось именно средствами html...
Но, все-равно, спасибо!

Comment: только на html этого сделать нельзя. Форму отправляет ТОЛЬКО <input type="submit"> и никакой другой элемент

Comment: ну почему же? <INPUT TYPE=IMAGE SRC="image.gif"> тоже, кажется, отправляет форму, нет? И разве IMAGE это не html?

Comment: Действительно такая возможность так-же существует.

ИМХО - это сахар, причём плохо реализованный, т.к. кнопку очистки формы виде картинки так не сделать.

Comment: ИМХО это костыль, а костыль не есть хорошо

Answer (score 0):

Лично я юзаю JQuery. Подключаешь библиотеку. Вешаешь любое событие на любой элемент и вызываешь к примеру функцию sendRequest();
Далее в теле функции используешь

```
sendRequest(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", //Либо "GET"
    url: "script.php", //Целевой скрипт
    data: "var1=value1&var2=value2", //Данные, которые посылаешь скрипту
    success: function(answer){ //Здесь call back виде функции с аргументом answer
       alert( "Прибыли данные: " + answer); //answer это то что вернул скрипт
  });
}
```

Comment: я уже сказал, через скрипты я уже все сделал. Интересна именно возможность отправки не через button.

Comment: самый адекватный подход + можно использовать абстракцию более высокго уровня ``jQuery.post()``

Comment: не спорю, но интересно найти другие пути.

Comment: Не знаю, конечно не уверен, но отправка http запроса реализована только в теге form и для того, чтобы отправить запрос другим методом необходимо либо юзать js либо ограничивать свои возможности формой. И вопрос следующего характера - неужели так много пользователей работающих с отключенным js?

Comment: Их так само "много" как и пользователей которые используют ie6- например, но суть даже не в этом. На самом деле я очень сильно сомневаюсь что ТСу это действительно необходимо